# SQL Access - comparing query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables in Access:

BANK(B_ID,B_NAME)
ACCOUNT(A_ID,A_SUM,ID_B)

What I have to do is compare all the banks and make a query, which will show me, which bank(or banks) have more accounts than in a specific bank "Bank A".

I'm just a beginner in SQL. I've tried all kinds of queries with GROUP BY and HAVING and SUM, but I can't seem to get them right. Can you, please, help?

Comment: in Access. I can't upload it here. But it doesn't matter, since the code should be easy to write without seeing it. I know I somehow need to compare like Count(A_ID)>A_ID in 'BankA'. I am so lost. :(

Comment: what's the relationship between `Bank` and `Account`?

Comment: I have many banks and many accounts. One account can have only one bank.

Answer (score 1):

```
select banks.b_name

from (
      select count(*) as total_accounts , b_name   from bank b inner 
      join account a on b.b_id = a.id_b
) as banks

where banks.total_accounts > ( select count(*)  
                              from bank 
                              inner join
                              account 
                              on bank.b_id = account.id_b
                              where bank.b_name = 'BankA'
                             )
```

Comment: It outputted a table with sum of all the accounts, that I have, NOT how many each bank has. :( I need to compare the number of accounts in different banks to the number of accounts in 'BankA' and output the names of those banks.

Comment: I changed my answer try it .

Comment: It outputs a clause error in FROM. :( But I found an answer! :) Thank you so much for helping, I really appreciate it!